# Uniform Parameter handle in SharpDx DirectX11 HLSL

Tags: c#, directx, handler, uniform, sharpdx

I'm wondering if there is another way to access uniform Parameters in SharpDx besides the constantbuffer

```
 cbuffer Variables : register(b0){
 float4 cL;
 }
```

I think the register(b0) tells the Datapointer which one to access. Anyways the Question is about another way like is it possible to get and set parameters like these

```
uniform float4 paraO;
uniform vector3 vecO;
uniform float para2;
```

I couldn't find a way to get or set their values within SharpDx or DirectX11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler should create a constant buffer for those parameters.

If you use SharpDX' effect framework, you can use the [effect's parameters](http://sharpdx.com/documentation/api/f-sharpdx-toolkit-graphics-effect-parameters) to get a handle to the variables..

Comment: I'm looking for a way without using the effect framework. So I tried to use the ShaderReflection.
but 
         for (int i = 0; i < sDesc.ConstantBuffers; ++i)
            {
                ShaderParameterDescription paramDesc =                   pRefelector.GetInputParameterDescription(i);
         MessageBox.Show(paramDesc.SemanticName);

I only get the variables within my 
         struct PS_IN
         {
             float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
             float4 col : COLOR;
 
         };

but not those in 
         cbuffer Variables : register(b0){
          float4 TestFarbe;
         }

Comment: Then you should use http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-d3dcompiler-shaderreflection-getconstantbuffer-1 and not the input parameters.

Comment: yes I know I've forgotten to add the code and did not used the ShaderReflectionVariable :/
Anyways I got now almost all the data I want. The only thing not working is this "shaderRefVar.Description.Name" I only get the first variable. So if  cbuffer Variables : register(b0){
 float4 cL;
 float4 uF;
 float3 ck;
 } 
I always get only "cL".

Comment: all working I had the ShaderReflectionVariable in the wrong loop